# Send GET request with JSON data from Axios to Asp.net core ActionResult without getting (415 Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, axios

I'm trying to make a GET request with JSON data using axios to aspnet core like so

```
  axios.get("http://localhost/api/tag/getnearby",{
     Latitude:24.470901,
     Longitude:39.612236,
     RangeInMeters:5000
  },{
     headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
        'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Content-Type, x-requested-with',
     }
  })
  .then(response => {
     console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(err =>  {
     console.log(err)
  })
```

Backend

```
[HttpGet("getnearby")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult GetNearby(GetNearbyRequest request)
{
    var tags = Tag.SelectNearby(Convert.ToDouble(request.Longitude),Convert.ToDouble(request.Latitude),Convert.ToUInt32(request.RangeInMeters));
    return Ok(new {tags = tags});
}


public class GetNearbyRequest
{
    public string Latitude {get;set;}
    public string Longitude {get;set;}
    public string RangeInMeters {get;set;}
}
```

However I always get **415 Unsupported media type** error in the response and the compiler doesn't hit a breakpoint inside the ActionResult.

The weired thing is I've tried to do the same request from an api client like Insomnia or PostMan and it worked fine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you sending Content-Type in a GET request?

Comment: Tried to mimic the headers from the insomnia api client, thought it could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With axios `get` method, the parameters passed to the background are string, it can not pass json, post method can realize.

You can add `[FromQuery]` in backend.

```
    public ActionResult GetNearby([FromQuery]GetNearbyRequest request)
    {
        //...
        return Ok(request);
    }
```

And the method `get` in axios should add `params`.

```
axios.get("https://localhost:44350/api/Tag/getnearby",
        {params:{
                Latitude:24.470901,
                Longitude:39.612236,
                RangeInMeters:5000
              }},{
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
                    'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Content-Type, x-requested-with',
                }
              })
              .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
              })
              .catch(err =>  {
                console.log(err)
              })
            }
```

The result returned by the backend.

[image]

Comment: Sending a Content-Type request header field when there's no content being sent still is incorrect. And, FWIW, sending charset=utf-8 on application/json is nonsense as well.